# First eigenvalue of Schrodinger operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, consider $L=\Delta+V$ where $\Delta=div\nabla$. According to section 8.12 in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book, if $V\in L^\infty(\Omega)$, then the Dirichlet spectrum of $L$ exists, and the first eigenvalue is simple.

(1) What is the weakest condition on $V$ such that the spectrum still exists?

(2) What is the condition on $V$ such that the first eigenvalue is positive?

I think this should have been well studied, but I haven't been able to find any good reference. If you are familiar with this, please let me know. Thanks for your help.